# Volume of the region lying inside circular and parabolic cylinders

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following problem:

Find the volume of the region lying inside the circular cylinder $x^2+y^2=2y$ and inside the parabolic cylinder $z^2 = y$.

To solve the problem, I did the following:

$x^2+y^2=2y \implies x^2 +(y-1)^2=1$. So we have a circle centered at $(0,1)$.

I think writing volume $V=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-2}^2(?)dA$ is not useful at this point. We have $z^2 =y$ too so the lower bound for $y$ must be $0$.

So, how can I calculate the volume, i.e., write down a double integral? Thanks.

Comment: have you studied cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: I'll post an answer at some point, but try to graph the volume in 3D and see how they intersect. The circular surface has an axis parallel to the $z$-axis while the parabolic surface's axis is on the $x$-axis, so figuring out the integral isn't going to be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the region in question

[image: cylinders]

First note that it's bounded above and below by the two halves of the parabolic cylinder, so we can write the $z$ limits as 
$$ -\sqrt{y} \le z \le \sqrt{y} $$

Now we need to put limits on the intersection curve, projected down to the $xy$-plane. This is just a circle centered at $(0,1)$ with radius $1$. You have two choices for the limits

$$ -\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2} \le x \le \sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}, \ 0 \le y \le 2 $$

or

$$ 1 - \sqrt{1-x^2} \le y \le 1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}, \ -1 \le x \le 1 $$

Putting it together, you'll get something like

$$ V = \int dV = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} dz\ dy\ dx $$

---

If you know how to integrate in cylindrical coordinates, the problem could be potentially easier. Let

$$ x = r\cos \theta, \ y = r\sin \theta, \ z = z $$

Then the intersection circle has the form
$$ r = 2\sin \theta $$

And the integral looks like
$$ V = \int dV = \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\sin\theta} \int_{-\sqrt{r\sin\theta}}^{\sqrt{r\sin\theta}} r \ dz \ dr \ d\theta $$

Comment: What software did you use to graph that?

Comment: [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/3d)

Comment: Thank you for help, I am reading it now. Also I would like to ask, how can we write down only 2 integrals like this one: 
https://image.ibb.co/f5LAA6/stackeee.png
This is the meaningless solution of the question...

Comment: It's the polar integral in the last line of the answer, with the $dz$ part solved. There are two symmetries: one through the $xy$ plane, and one through the $y$-axis (or the line $\theta = \pi/2$)

Answer (score 0):

$z$ is bounded below by $-\sqrt y$ and above by $\sqrt y$.

$x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 1 \implies y = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}$

So $y$ is bounded at the "back" by $1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ and at the "front" by $1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

$x$ is bounded to the left by $-1$ and to the right by $1$ (these are the minimum and maximum $x$-values that exist on the circle).

So$$V=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}}^{1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y} 1 \, \mathrm dz \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx$$

Comment: Your $y$ equation is not quite right

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've fixed it now, thanks.